# how to check the value in the tuple

Tags: python, list

im making this game where i have to distrbute cards among players and check the card's value wether its bigger or smaller and the bigger one wins but the problem im facing is that the cards are in a tuple and i cant access the index of them. how can this be made using this code?
**strong text**here is my code:

```
import random
import time

card_deck = [ ('♥', 2),('♥', 3), ('♥', 4),('♥', 5),('♥', 6),('♥', 7), ('♥', 8), ('♥', 9), ('♥', 10), ('♥', 'B'), ('♥', 'D'),
             ('♥', 'K'), ('♥', 'A'), ('♦', 2),('♦', 3), ('♦', 4),('♦', 5),('♦', 6), ('♦', 7), ('♦', 8), ('♦', 9), ('♦', 10),
             ('♦', 'B'), ('♦', 'D'), ('♦', 'K'), ('♦', 'A'), ('♣', 2),('♣', 3), ('♣', 4),('♣', 5),('♣', 6), ('♣', 7),
             ('♣', 8), ('♣', 9), ('♣', 10), ('♣', 'B'), ('♣', 'D'), ('♣', 'K'),
             ('♣', 'A'), ('♠', 2),('♠', 3), ('♠', 4),('♠', 5),('♠', 6), ('♠', 7), ('♠', 8), ('♠', 9), ('♠', 10), ('♠', 'B'),
             ('♠', 'D'), ('♠', 'K'), ('♠', 'A')]




def deal_cards():
    players = []
    #players_cards
    player1 = []
    player2 = []
    player3 = []
    player4 = []
    player5 = []
    #counter
    player1_counter = 0
    player2_counter = 0
    player3_counter = 0
    player4_counter = 0
    player5_counter = 0

    print("----------> Welcome to 'Wizard mal anders' <-----------")
    player_number = int(input("please enter the number of players: 2-5 "))
    number_of_rounds = 52 // int(player_number)

    for i in range(int(player_number)):
        player_names = input("Enter players' names: ")
        players.append(player_names)
    random.shuffle(card_deck)

    rounds = number_of_rounds
    #rounds = 3  # fixed for now
    for index, r in enumerate(range(1, rounds + 1), start=1):
        print(f"Round > {r}")
        for i in range(player_number):
            for inner in range(0, index):
                card = random.randint(0, len(card_deck))
                player1.append(card_deck[card])
                print(player1)
                print(f"card_deck > {card_deck[card]}")


#check the cards value
#counter for points

'''def dealCards():
    rounds = 3 # fixed for now
    for index,r in enumerate(range(1,rounds+1), start=1):
        print(f"Round > {r}")
        for inner in range(0,index):
            card = random.randint(0,len(card_deck))
            print(f"card_deck > {card_deck[card]}")'''




def create_cards():
    return dict.fromkeys(card_deck)






print(create_cards())
print(deal_cards())
```

Comment: *"the cards are in a tuple and i cant access the index of them"* - why not? Tuples are indexable - `(1, 2)[0]` gives `1`...

Comment: cuz there are in a list, its a tuple in a list, the output is [('♣', 3)]

Answer (score 1):

You can still use index

```
player[indexOfCard][IndexOfValue]

#ex
player[0][1] # 2
```

this may help to uderstand
https://www.learnbyexample.org/python-nested-list/

Comment: well the thing is that they arent in a nested list rather they are in a tuple in a list

Comment: @MohamedSayed: Lists and tuples can both be indexed the same way.

Comment: try run next code:
```
card =[("♥",2)]
print(card[0][1])
```

Comment: Biggest difference between tuple and list is that you cant change values of tuple. otherwise they work almost the same